# Incorrect quote format with IEEE style and Spanish babel

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, babel, ieee-style

I'm using LaTeX for the first time and I'm having some problems with the citations. Specifically, I have to use IEEE citation style in Spanish, and websites are giving me headaches. I would like to achieve something similar to this:

[image]

i.e. print a website reference with no authors, title enclosed in double quote marks, website's name in italics, year of publication and `[Online]. Avalilable:` should be equivalent to `[En línea]. Disponible en:`. However, right now I'm using `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}` and `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`, and this is the result I'm getting, totally different to what I was expecting:

[image]

This is my .bib file:

```
@electronic{freno_disco,
    title = {{Freno de disco}},
    organization = {{Wikipedia}},
    url = "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freno_de_disco",
    year = 2016,
    urldate = {2016-06-27}
}
```

And a MWE:

```
\documentclass [11pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I've tried a lot of different things and I couldn't get any close to the expected result. I don't mind replacing `biblatex` with `bibtex`, or modifying the IEEE style file, but I would need some instructions on how to change it. I'm using Overleaf with XeLaTeX. If you need more info, please ask me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX stackexchange. Could you give a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/why-does-tex-require-such-elaborate-mwes)? You can use [filecontents](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) to include the bib file.

Comment: I've edited my post adding the MWE, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using one style (IEEE style), and you want a different style. Except for the quotation marks, the format that you get, is the one intended by IEEE (see misc entry [here](https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-ieeetran-ieeetran/)).

If you want to use double quotes instead of guillemets, just do not use the csquotes package, or pass the `style=english` option so that csquotes does not use the sytle taken from babel.

```
\documentclass [11pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@electronic{freno_disco,
    title = {{Freno de disco}},
    organization = {{Wikipedia}},
    url = "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freno_de_disco",
    year = 2016,
    urldate = {2016-06-27}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to modify the translation of "Available", you can use the biblatex command `\DefineBibliographyStrings` in the preamble:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  url = {[En línea]. Disponible en:},
}
```

You have the details [here (section 3.10)](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)

Finally, if you want to custom the formatting of some fields, you must read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles). For example:

```
\documentclass [11pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  url = {[En línea]. Disponible en:},
}
\DeclareListFormat[online]{organization}{%
  \mkbibemph{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
  {\addcomma\space}
{}}

\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@electronic{freno_disco,
    title = {{Freno de disco}},
    organization = {{Wikipedia}},
    url = "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freno_de_disco",
    year = 2016,
    urldate = {2016-06-27}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]